# at a rate unparalleled ( question about the position of the adjective)

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, adjectives, attributives

I got stuck with this sentence 'This is also a period of enormous physical change and adolescents experience changes in their physical development **at a rate unparalleled** since infancy.'.
I am confused about why the adjective '**unparalleled**' is put behind the noun'**rate**'.  Are there any special functions or meanings? And can anybody tell me how to analyse this structure grammatically? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you wanted to put the adjective *before* the noun, it would have to be the *whole* adjective. It might look a bit "forced", but native speakers certainly wouldn't argue with the *syntactic* validity of *...at an **unparalleled-since-infancy** rate* (the hyphens are just an orthographic courtesy to help the reader parse the utterance correctly).

Answer (score 0):

The whole phrase *unparalleled since infancy* describes *rate.* (Their bodies change at a faster rate than they have experienced since they were babies.)

The sentence wouldn't make sense if the phrase was split up in order to put the adjective before the noun.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is an example of [whiz-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info#:%7E:text=Whiz%2Ddeletion%20is%20a%20type,reduced%20by%20whiz%2Ddeletion%5D), where a relative pronoun and be-verb are omitted from a relative clause. Here is the sentence with the relative pronoun and be-verb present:

> This is also a period of enormous physical change and adolescents experience changes in their physical development at a rate **which is** unparalleled since infancy.

Comment: Thank you so much！ I think I made a mistake. I separated the word 'unparalleled' and the phrase 'since infancy' , so it led to my misunderstanding.